# Retrieve categories data with its subcategories data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I have this code from another post :

```
SELECT bar
  FROM (SELECT S.subcategoryname As bar, 
               C.CategoryName AS SortName,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CategoryName 
                                      ORDER BY subcategoryname) As RowNum
          FROM category C 
     LEFT JOIN subCategory S ON C.CategoryID = S.CategoryID 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C.CategoryName As bar, 
               C.CategoryName AS SortName, 
               0
          FROM category C) foo
ORDER BY foo.SortName, RowNum
```

It works, but how can I retrieve more than just `categoryName` and `subCategoryName`. Is there a way to retrieve data from all columns?

[image]

my code:

```
select  * from (select s.titlu_subcerinta as bar,c.titlu_Cerinta As SortName, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by c.titlu_Cerinta order by titlu_subcerinta) as RowNum
from cerinteProiect c left join subcerinteProiect s on c.id_cerinta = s.id_cerinta
UNION ALL
select c.titlu_Cerinta As bar, c.titlu_Cerinta As SortName,0
from cerinteProiect c
)
foo
order by
foo.SortName,RowNum
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "data from all the columns".  If you want all the columns in the derived table/inline view (the SELECT in the FROM clause), then use `SELECT *`.  Otherwise, we don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: if I use SELECT * I get error regarding UNION statement...

Comment: and Yes I would like all the collumns in the derived table

Comment: Doesn't make sense - the derived table wouldn't return `bar` if the UNION didn't work.  The * goes on the outer query, not the inner one.

Comment: yeah, but I still don't get more info than bar,Sortname, an rownum

Comment: select  * from (select s.titlu_subcerinta as bar,c.titlu_Cerinta As SortName, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by c.titlu_Cerinta order by titlu_subcerinta) as RowNum
from cerinteProiect c left join subcerinteProiect s on c.id_cerinta = s.id_cerinta
UNION ALL
select c.titlu_Cerinta As bar, c.titlu_Cerinta As SortName,0
from cerinteProiect c
)
foo
order by
foo.SortName,RowNum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OMG Ponies said, the first `SELECT FROM` is pulling data from `foo`. If you don't return all columns from C in there, your outer query has no way to get them.

Expand both parts of your inner query to capture the whole table, like as follows:

```
SELECT * --grab everything you get in the subquery
  FROM (SELECT S.subcategoryname As bar, 
               C.* --note how this grabs EVERYTHING in Category, as you want
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CategoryName 
                                      ORDER BY subcategoryname) As RowNum
          FROM category C 
     LEFT JOIN subCategory S ON C.CategoryID = S.CategoryID 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C.CategoryName As bar, 
               C.*, --this grabs everything again
               0
          FROM category C) foo
ORDER BY CategoryName, RowNum --both of these come from foo - no need to specify it
```

Comment: yeah,this is great!thanks! but what about the info for subcategory?

Comment: Then you have to manually `SELECT` each column in the subquery, because `*` won't automatically correct duplicate column names between `C` and `S`. You can still use the star in the outer query. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT S.col1 AS S_Col1, S.col2 AS S_Col2 .... C.Col1 AS C_Col1 ... FROM C LEFT JOIN S` .

Comment: You would also need to do the same thing to the `UNION ALL` part.

Comment: `Select * from (Select s.titlu_subcerinta as bar,s.autor as autorSubcerinta, c.titlu_cerinta,c.autor as autorCerinta , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.titlu_cerinta order by titlu_subcerinta) as RowNum 
from cerinteProiect c 
left join subcerinteProiect s on c.id_cerinta = s.id_cerinta
union all
select c.titlu_cerinta as bar,c.autor as autorCerinta,s.autor as autorSubcerinta,0
from cerinteProiect c)foo
order by titlu_cerinta,RowNum`

Comment: I get this error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "s.autor" could not be bound.
Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @TBogdan, you need to code-format your code, even in comments. Click the "Help" button next to the comment box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13915/discussion-between-arithmomaniac-and-tbogdan)